# Web3.js eth.net or contract.methods.balanceOf methods not working with latest MetaMask extension

Tags: javascript, angular, web3js, metamask, ganache

I am learning dapps, and trying to create existing react tutorial from Dapp university ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgXQC4dbGUE ) to Angular 11 project.
truffle (v5.4.1), web3.js ( v1.4.0), Ganache, MetaMask chrome extension version 9.8.2

As per MetaMask there are breaking changes, check following link https://medium.com/metamask/breaking-changes-to-the-metamask-provider-are-here-7b11c9388be9

> As of today, MetaMask has stopped injecting window.web3, and made a limited number of breaking changes to our Ethereum Provider API (window.ethereum).

Here is my code. Please check comments added in code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import DaiToken from '../../build/contracts/DaiToken.json';
import DappToken from '../../build/contracts/DappToken.json';
import TokenFarm from '../../build/contracts/TokenFarm.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  accounts: any;
  investorAccount: string = '0x0';
  daiToken: any = {};
  dappToken: any = {};
  tokenFarm: any = {};
  daiTokenBalance: string = '0';
  dappTokenBalance: string = '0';
  stakingBalance: string = '0';
  loading: boolean = true;
  web3: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bootstrapWeb3();
  }

  async bootstrapWeb3() {
    await this.loadWeb3();
    await this.loadBlockchainData();
  }

  async loadWeb3() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      this.accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
      });
      // await window.ethereum.enable();  // no longer required

      this.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      
    } else {
      window.alert(
        'Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!'
      );
    }
  }

  async loadBlockchainData() {    
    // const accounts = await this.web3.eth.getAccounts();  <----- Not working with latest metamask changes
    // 'eth_requestAccounts' returns accounts

    this.investorAccount = this.accounts[0];

    try {

      // const networkId = await this.web3.eth.net.getId().then(console.log);
      // this.web3.eth.net.getId() method Not working, nothing happens, no error

      // but method below returns networkId
      const networkId = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: 'net_version',
      });

      const daiTokenData = DaiToken.networks[networkId];

      // Load DaiToken
      if (daiTokenData) {
        // Contract
        const daiToken = new this.web3.eth.Contract(
          DaiToken.abi,
          daiTokenData.address
        );

        this.daiToken = daiToken;

        //  balanceOf not working, nothing happens, no error
        let daiTokenBalance = await daiToken.methods.balanceOf(this.investorAccount).call();

        this.daiTokenBalance = daiTokenBalance.toString();
      } else {
        window.alert('DaiToken contract not deployed to detected network.');
      }      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Q. Why web3 methods are not working e.g. window.web3.eth.net.getId() or window.web3.eth.getBalance or getAccounts or contract methods like contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call() ?
Q. Does this mean there is no need of web3js or it's methods, Using JSON RPC methods as specified by MetaMask is enough? https://metamask.github.io/api-playground/api-documentation.

If anybody has latest updated javascript example code please post.

Comment: Has `this.account` valid data? Why do you assign `window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)`? Can you try `this.web3 = new Web3(..)`? Do you have an example project to test?

Comment: Hi @Ismael ,  yes,  
`this.accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
      });`   As per new MetaMask changes above code returns account details.

I have uploaded project to Github, you can clone it. Follow Readme.md file for installation instructions
[link] (https://github.com/rahulkolage/defi-farm-tutorial)